# Spring Boot CORS 403 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, cors

I'm learning to develop a RESTful application with Spring Boot 1.5.2 as server and angularJS 1.6 as client. When I try to login from "localhost:9000/login" with "localhost:8080/login", I keep getting a 403 response.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/login. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

~

```
import org.apache.catalina.filters.*;
import org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/login", "logout", "/customers").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .cors()
                    .disable();
    }


    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
        return repository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

~

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
@Component
class SimpleCORSFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

    public SimpleCORSFilter() {
        log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, HEAD, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, z-requested-with, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

How do I properly set up spring boot security to allow it to work with angularJS without CORS and CSRF problem?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the filter in the proper order, before the Web Security Filter, as follows:

```
.addFilterBefore(
    new LoginFilter(new SimpleCORSFilter()),
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "**", maxAge = 3600)
```

Does the trick, but I don't think it's a very robust solution. So far, I find that some of my endpoints work with it, and some are still providing the CORS error.
Still a quick hack nonetheless, for bigger projects I think setting up CORSFilters is the way to go, which I believe is what you were attempting to do.